# Cygwin "cannot find -lreadline"

Tags: c, cygwin, readline

I'm having a problem with creating a Makefile in C++. I need to link the readline library with my code but I keep getting this error.

> `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lreadline collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [Makefile:5: tokenizer] Error 1`

I currently have my readline folder, which I have downloaded from the GNU Readline library site, in cygwin64/usr/include folder.

In my tokenizer.cpp code, I also have `#include <readline/readline.h>`, but I previously kept getting an error which was fixed by putting my readline folder in the directory it is in right now, so I assumed this was the correct place to put it until this error came up.

In my cygwin/usr directory, I don't have a lib directory in it, so I'm not sure  if moving or copying my readline folder to another directory would fix the problem. Aside from that, I'm not really sure what else could be wrong aside from my Makefile itself

```
CC=gcc

tokenizer : tokenizer.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ -g $< -lreadline.c
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: -l is used to specify the shortcut name for a library necessary for the link step in building an executable (e.g. -lcurl identifies the libcurl.a library).  You have specified -lreadline.c, which would mean a library of libreadline.c.a... probably not what you meant.  Additionally, readline.c is "probably" the C source code for the "readline" function.  Lastly, I believe you are invoking the C compiler (i.e. gcc), instead of the C++ compiler (i.e. g++)...

Comment: the header file: `readline.h` should go in the directory: `/usr/include`  The library file: `libreadline.a` (or libreadline.so) could be placed in the same directory as your source (or in the `/usr/lib` directory

Comment: @user3629249 that's strange, I don't seem to have the libreadline.a file in the package I downloaded. I currently have readline ver 8.0 from the case.edu site. Is there anywhere else (reliable) I could get it?

Comment: Can you please show the compiler command before the error ? Please also show the output of `cycheck -c libreadline-devel`

Comment: Did you get any answer to your question?? I am stuck with this same problem. I have tried every available answer here and it still can't find -lreadline

Answer (score 2):

Use `cygcheck` to find the package containing the proper import library (ending in `dll.a` for shared ones)

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/lib/libreadline.dll.a
Found 3 matches for usr/lib/libreadline.dll.a
...
libreadline-devel-7.0.3-3 - libreadline-devel: GNU readline and history libraries (development)
```

Use setup to install the `libreadline-devel`

[image]

Comment: I was able to successfully install the package, but I'm still having the same issue where libreadline cannot be found :( I've tried the .dll.a and .a file and both gave me the same error still

Comment: You need to include `-lreadline7` to get the linker to use `/bin/cygreadline7.dll`.

Comment: @DougHenderson that is wrong. `-lreadline` will proper link with it

Answer (score 0):

To make your Cygwin life easier, use [apt-cyg](https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg) to download the required `libreadline` dependencies:

```
apt-cyg install libreadline7 libreadline-devel mingw64-i686-readline mingw64-x86_64-readline
```

Comment: as the compiling is for cygwin only `libreadline-devel` is needed. You are pulling non needed cross compilers libraries.

Comment: Yeah, but OP didn't say what he already added, so I just took pre-cautinary (and non-damaging) approach. :)